# Why is angular-promise-tracker not working for me?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've installed [angular-promise-tracker](https://github.com/ajoslin/angular-promise-tracker) and I think I'm close to getting it working.  The problem I'm having is that the "loading" text isn't showing.  The data is fetched and does show when outputting it to the console.

So it appears that `ng-show="loadingTracker.active()"` isn't working.  I can't see what I'm doing wrong with this.

Any help with this would be sincerely appreciated - as always :)

Here's my code:

HTML

```
<button ng-controller="weatherCtrl" 
        ng-model="hotel" 
        class="btn btn-default" 
        ng-click="loadWeather(hotel, $index)">
        {{buttonText}} more</button>
<div collapse="isCollapsed">
    <div class="well well-lg more-detail">
        {{hotel.Description}}
        <br /><br />
            <div>
                <div class="my-super-awesome-loading-box" 
                     ng-show="loadingTracker.active()">
                     Loading..
                </div>                        
            </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

JS

```
.controller('weatherCtrl', function ($scope, weather, $timeout, promiseTracker){
   $scope.loadingTracker = promiseTracker();
   $scope.buttonText= 'Load'
   $scope.loadedHotelDetails=[];
   $scope.loadWeather = function(hotel, index) {
      // console.log('loadWeather')           
      weather.get({tracker: $scope.loadingTracker}, function (data){
      console.log(data)
      $scope.loadedHotelDetails.push(index)
   })
})



angular.module('weather', [])
    .factory('weather', function($http) {
         var weather = {};
         weather.get = function(params, callback) {
            $http.get('/php/weather.php', {params: {tracker: params.tracker, page: params.page}}).success(function(data) {
             callback(data);
            });
         };
         return weather;
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used this module, but from the examples on github, I think you're supposed to call it like this in `weather`:

```
     weather.get = function(params, callback) {
        $http.get('/php/weather.php', {tracker: params.tracker, page: params.page}).success(function(data) {
         callback(data);
        });
     };
```

Comment: And on a side note: I personally find it more _angularish_ to return the promise generated by the `http.get` call instead of passing in a callback.

Comment: Yeah I was intending updating the code to return the promise, just not done it yet.  Your code has helped to show the 'loading' message but the request isn't made.  I'll need to spend a bit more time on this I think

Answer (score 0):

Got it sorted, this is the code I needed:

```
.factory('weather', function($http) {
  var weather = {};
  weather.get = function(params) {
    return $http.get('/php/weather.php', {tracker: params.tracker, page: params.page});
  };
  return weather;
});
```

Comment: That's exactly the change I posted in my answer, isn't it? The most important change being not to wrap all parameters in a property `params`.

Comment: Yeah yours is virtually identical, just posting my exaxt solution, just incase I need to refer to it again (or for anyone else that might want to look at it).  I gave you the credit for the answer, thank you :)